# Why are there ads inside trams which ask me to use the tram?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory

When I sit in my local tram/bus/any public transport, I notice ads which ask me to use the transport system which I *do currently* use.

Seriously, I'm already using it at that time. Why placing ads for the same?

My ideas:

- No other party was interested in placing an ad, so use the space for something less useless than *nothing*
- *Repeat things often* theory (to deeply burn this into my mind)
- To make people using it only sometimes use it more often
- That people like me ask this stuff and discuss it with their friends or in the internet (scnr)

Comment: Nice theories. Perhaps the ad space is effectively no-cost as well. Why not toot your own horn? (especially in a tram) My older brother used to say something like your last point: "*It's to make people like you ask dumb questions.*"

Comment: I voted to keep this question open, because there is no Marketing stack where it could probably fit better, I think it can then be answered from the cognitive-phycology angle.

Comment: What would a suitable answer to this question look like? A comparison of studies showing the effectiveness of advertising in terms of repetition vs. reinforcing exiting/current behaviours?